# Opening print Screen(window.print) in new tab freezes the Parent window of Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React Component, I have a Print Button on Click of which i am calling a function to open print Dialouge box in new tab.

The code for Print function is :

```
var winPrint = window.open('', '',)
winPrint.document.write('<html><head><title></title></head><body>Some text</body></html>')
winPrint.document.close()
winPrint.focus()
winPrint.print()
winPrint.close()
```

Now when this opens a Print dialouge box in new tab and if user doesnt take any action on Print dialouge box, then my Parent is also freezed. If we close the Print dialouge box then my Parent window also gets active.

So, i want to make my Parent window always active, irrespective user takes any action on Print dialouge box or not.

I have also tried rel="noopener" with window.open but its not working.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Issue seems to be in Chrome but in firefox it works fine after adding rel = "noopener" in window. open.
But how to make it works in Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print), "In most browsers, this method will block while the print dialog is open". In other words, calling `print()` will block that thread (like if you called `alert()`) until the user finishes interacting with that element.

This is by design, so there likely isn't any way around it. The page I linked does note that recent versions of Safari return immediately, which would mean the parent doesn't freeze like you describe, but that is browser specific.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the input. But by adding the additional paramter  of rel = "noopener", in window.open, unfreezes the parent tab in firefox but why the same solution doesn't works in Chrome?

Comment: The browser gets to choose how it is implemented, since the exact behavior isn't defined in the specification. So for whatever reason, in Firefox they have decided that when `rel="noopener"` (which only creates a new context) is used, `print()` will be non-blocking, whereas in Chrome they have decided otherwise. Although the browsers 'read' the same code, they don't run it in the same way, because they are built off different engines, which leads to all manner of inconsistencies between them, like this.